# How to call draw method outside paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, draw, paintcomponent

I have an assignment where I have to draw a circle in a panel and with that circle calculate the reaction time of the user when the circle changes size or color. I've got the paintComponent method. But now I have to call the method for the circles in another class and I don't know how to do that. Can someone please help me with this?

Here is my class where paintComponent is written:

```
public class ReactionPanel extends JPanel {

boolean setSmallCircle, setInitialCircle;
Color color = new Color (255,0,0); //color  = red
Color c = new Color (255,255,0); //color = yellow
int size;
int x = 250;
int y = x;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  super.paintComponent(g);
  if (setInitialCircle){
    size = 50;
  }
  if (setSmallCircle) {
    size = 50;
  }
  else {
    size = 150;
  }
  g.drawOval(x,y,size,size);
  g.fillOval(x,y,size,size);
}
void setInitialCircle(Graphics g, Color color){
  g.setColor(color);
}
void setSmallCircle(Graphics g, Color c){
  g.setColor(c);
}
void setBigCircle(Graphics g, Color c){
  g.setColor(c);
}
}
```

Now I would need those (`setInitialCircle` etc) and call them in my main class ReactionExperiment like so:

```
void startTest(){
//draw red circle
}
```

How do I do this? 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have two classes, and you'd like to call a public function defined in one from the other. Since the method is not a static method, you'd have to instantiate an object for the class like -

```
ReactionPanel obj = new ReactionPanel();
```

then using this object, you can call any method defined in the first class, like

```
obj.paintComponent(g);   // you'll have to define g first though
```

Comment: But using `obj.paintComponent(g)` how will that get me the specific method like `setSmallCircle`? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm just trying to understand and learn

Comment: This was just an example, all you'll have to do is 


   " obj.setSmallCircle(g,c); // define g and c first "


No question is stupid, though you have to carefully frame it on StackOverflow !

Comment: Oh waw that was very stupid of me, I was accidentally `reactionPanel.setSmallcircle(g,color);` instead of with capital C. But thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: using a _protected_ method as an example of how-to call methods is a bit ... unfortunate :-) Consider editing and using some other method.

Comment: -1, @Laynie_x, You should NOT be invoking paintComponent() directly. You should be using `obj.repaint()` to tell a component to repaint itself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want this ?

```
ReactionPanel reactionPanel = new ReactionPanel();
reactionPanel.setSmallCircle(x, x);
```

What this code does it instantiates ReactionPanel (it makes a new instance of it). As such you can then use its methods in another class.

Comment: I've actually tried that already but it gives me these errors `setSmallCircle(java.awt.Graphics,java.awt.Color) in ReactionExperiment.ReactionPanel cannot be applied to (int,int)` and `x is not public in java.awt.Component; cannot be accessed from outside package`

Comment: emm.... (x, x) you meant to substitute these with whatever parameters you desire. X was just an example. You need to pass in the parameters the method is expecting

Comment: Oh okay, cause I have x defined in my setSmallCircle method so I thought I wouldn't have to define it again. But even so it still gives me the first error I mentioned

Comment: because it seems like you are still passing wrong arguments. Your method expects 2 int values, but perhaps you are declaring or passing not int value. So either you can cast it (whatever value is that) or you need to change it so the method receives appropriate parameters

Comment: are you trying to pass two ints instead of Graphic and Color variable ?

Comment: Yes, I've realized my mistake. Thank you for your help :)